# How can I make building an Xcode target depend on a shell script?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, build, shell, dependencies

I have a shell script that runs as part of a Run Script phase in my targets that conditionally copies some files into the product. If I modify the shell script then rebuild, the script is not run because the target does not know that there is a dependency there.

How can I add a dependency so that modifications to the shell script cause the product to be rebuilt, either partly or completely? I can't do it directly through the Add Dependency dialog.

Comment: You can use 'touch' to mark a file on disk 'dirty'- if you did so to a source file (or xcode project?) it will be recompiled the next time arount. Not sure how to do it in the same build step, as the dependencies are calculated *before* anything is run... I'd be interested in a solution here, too.

Answer (score 2):

Make a new target just for your script, have it copy its files into a temporary staging folder or something, make your main target depend upon it and do a second copy of its results.